# DS201: Foundations of Apache Cassandra - Step 1 or 2 lab - error : tar: This does not look like a tar archive

Tags: cassandra

Just started the DS201 lab.  using the online lab where we download and untar cassandra

```
curl https://dlcdn.apache.org/cassandra/4.1.0/apache-cassandra-4.1.0-bin.tar.gz \
```

but getting this error:

```
gitpod /workspace/ds201-lab01 (main) $ tar xf apache-cassandra-4.1.0-bin.tar.gz
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
```

Just thought I would mention that there is a problem with the lab documentation.

https://datastaxacad-ds201lab01-cvobpct6yi5.ws-us106.gitpod.io/

I believe the problem is that apache-cassandra-4.1.0-bin.tar.gz is not being fully downloaded to the gitpod.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this before, too. Go ahead and replace that step with this:

```
curl https://dlcdn.apache.org/cassandra/4.1.3/apache-cassandra-4.1.3-bin.tar.gz \
    --output apache-cassandra-4.1.3-bin.tar.gz
```

This will also get you the latest version of 4.1. Let me see if I can get that fixed-up.

Answer (score 0):

In this location we only keep the latest of each patch version: https://dlcdn.apache.org/cassandra

Older versions you will find here: https://archive.apache.org/dist/cassandra/
(but take care, archives is slower and overuse will get you blacklisted)